# awk print a specific column from multiple files to a new file

Tags: shell, awk

I have few files. e.g.

```
file1.txt
1 2 3 4
2 3 3 4
3 2 4 2
7 2 0 0
1 2 9 9
3 0 9 0

file2.txt
3
4
2
33
NAN
NAN

file3.txt
2
4
4
NAN
NAN
NAN
```

I would like to print 1st column from each file in a new file with replacing NAN to "?".

The desire output file:

```
ofile.txt
1 3  2
2 4  4
3 2  4
7 33 ?
1 ?  ?
3 ?  ?
```

I was trying with `awk '$1 {print}' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > ofile.txt`
but it is not printing my desire output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this single `awk` to get this output:

```
awk '{s[FNR] = (s[FNR] == "" ? "" : s[FNR] "\t") ($1 == "NAN" ? "?" : $1)}
     END{for (i=1; i<=length(s); i++) print s[i]}' file[123].txt
```

```
1   3   2
2   4   4
3   2   4
7   33  ?
1   ?   ?
3   ?   ?
```

To store output in a file use `> ofile.txt` at the end of above command.

Comment: Tank you. It is working with the given example. But while executing for my original data, it is not printing with correct format.  some entries are printing closer to its previous column. Would you please suggest to set some format. Each entries should be with %5s.

Comment: Oh that is because your input files have DOS line breaks or `\r`. You can remove them using `dos2unix` command first.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has control M characters in his/her Input_file so adding solution as per that now. This should remove control M characters from Input_files too.

```
paste <(awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");print $1}' file1) file2 file3 | awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");gsub(/NAN/,"?")} 1'
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' file1) file2 file3 | awk '{gsub(/NAN/,"?")} 1'
```

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh123. It is showing: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Kay, it worked fine for me. Tested it on my system successfully

Comment: It is working as a command. But it showing syntax error when I wrote it inside the script.

Comment: @Kay, When I checked this command it is working for me even for redirecting its output to a out file too.

Comment: @Kay, Could you please check my EDIT solution if that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple `awk`

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' file1 ) <(awk '{print $1}' file2 ) <(awk '{print $1}' file3) | sed 's/NAN/\?/g'
```

or

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' file1 ) <(awk '{print $1}' file2 ) <(awk '{print $1}' file3) |awk '{gsub("NAN", "?", $0); print}'
```

Comment: IMHO, file2 and file3 already have only 1 column so you could avoid those 2 awks there. Then if you do so it becomes almost my suggested solution, Good try though, keep up the learning, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, I misunderstood file 2 and file 3 and straight go for printing column 1.Thanks for make it  in my notice, but it working for multiple columns :-).